# After trying to install desktop, cannot get to login

Tags: desktop-environments

I have tried to install various desktops on what started as a Ubuntu Server install.

At one stage, it would go to a login screen and it would let me login to the default user, but not to any other user ids.

Then I tried to install some more desktops and all I can get now is a black screen with a mouse pointer.

I can also get to a command line using ctrl+alt+f2.

Does anyone know how I should fix this?

Comment: The information you have provided isn't enough to allow assessment of the likely fault. Reccommendation: If you DON'T have *experience* with running a server, skip the server versions. Use the standard desktop version and get that running. After that get e.g. a Raspberry Pie and build your experience with it.

Comment: One could GUESS that there is a display driver problem, leaving you with the shell prompt/login as only viable option. Please provide details on display hardware and computer/laptop(?).

Comment: @Hannu what additional information would be useful?   I had a working desktop earlier, so I do not think this is a display driver issue. It's a Rock Pi 4 ie similar to a Raspberry Pi 4. Are there any log files that I can look at so I can narrow down the issue?

Comment: Use ctrl+alt+f2 and then type `dmesg | less` (press ENTER); in this state I believe you can now search in the text by pressing `/` followed by any text to look for; e.g. error, fail, disabled, ...   `?` will show all the options you have available while "less" is running.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all I needed to do was

dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

And change the display manager to lightdm